# Get label of other foreign key in belongs to many query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have four tables

1- users, 2- self_jobs, 3- users_jobs, 4- statuses

Users jobs is pivot table with users and self jobs save jobs for each user. Now I have a query for that to return all jobs for each user and information about them.
Here it is:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\SelfJob','users_jobs','user_id','self_job_id')->withPivot(['priority','status_id'])->withTimestamps();
```

As you can see I want other columns (priority and status_id) from my pivot table. Status_id is also foreign key for status table.
How can I change my query in a way that join to statuses table and return label of status that I save the id of it in my users_jobs table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without using pivot model, just create a Model for `users_jobs` and add belongs to relation in it for `job`, `user` and `status`

**User Model**

```
public function userJobs(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\UserJob','user_id');
}
```

**UserJob model**

```
class UserJob extends Model {
    protected $table = 'users_jobs';

    public function user(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function job(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Job', 'self_job_id');
    }


    public function status(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Status');
    }
}
```

**Fetch Data**

```
$user = User::with('userJobs', 'userJobs.job', 'userJobs.status')->find($userId);

foreach($user->userJobs as $userJob){
   dd($userJob->priority);
   dd($userJob->status->label);
}
```

Comment: i create status model but i face error that app/status not found !

Comment: where did you created `status` model ?

Comment: in the root of app folder

Comment: check name space, first letter. it should be `Status` class inside `app` folder with namespace `App`

Comment: query dosent return pivot values

Comment: try this dd($job->pivot) and see what is the output

Comment: I print $job and there isn't any pivot value

Comment: Property [pivot] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: my mistake i have used `App/Status` in relationship should be `App\Status`, updated answer

Comment: check your table and test for the user that has all these relations, after test you can add condition

Comment: should i add any function to mu status model?

Comment: no, you don't need to add anything in it, what error are you getting ?

Comment: @FarzaneKhazaei if you have not solved your problem yet, i have updated answer. Just added `->withPivot('price', 'status_id')` in  `User` model `jobs` relation. I have tested the code and it is working

Comment: i dont have label in my result :(

Comment: what field you have in status model ? you have mention `return label of status` in your question

Comment: i print $userJobs but ther is no status in it  (i have status method in my model)

Comment: you have to loop `$userJobs` and then print `$userJob->status`, use the same as it is in answer. did you create `UserJob` model ?